# Parallel resistors circuit: remove random resistors and from the total resistance know which were removed

Tags: resistors, parallel, calculation

[image]

This is more of a mathematics question than an electronics one.
With this circuit, I want to know the state of the switches above the resistors, without looking at them.

The use case is that I have a working live circuit, fed into a microcontroller's ADC, and I want to know if a resistor was removed in a matrix.

The matrix is a 7x7, where in each position I have a resistor that can be removed. So if I have 7 resistors in parallel in each row, I need 7 ADC inputs to the microcontroller.

So, when someone removes a resistor, I want to know which one was removed by reading the voltage. Think of it like a breakable touch screen, in which I want to know which resistor was broken, instead of touched (knowing which one was touched before being broken would be great too)

I know it's possible. We have a voltmeter. And all resistors have a different value.
We just need to build a 2^3=8 row table with possible values. Every single combination will result in a different voltage in the voltmeter.

But this is a tremendous job for a bigger circuit with more resistors in parallel.

I don't want to build that table. I want a mathematical solution that can give me the state of every switch just by looking at the voltmeter.

TLDR: Can I know the state of each of the switches just by looking at the voltmeter voltage?

Comment: @Ber Bn A better question would be more of why you would want to do this cause I strongly suspect there are better ways to solve your actual problem.

Comment: The user will be able to physically remove a resistor from the circuit. But I have no way of knowing it. There's no feedback about it. And that's the point: I want to monitor which resistors were removed

Comment: If that's the case, then brute forcing the table is easy to do in Excel. Even for dozens of resistors. The resistor values have to be chosen so that all combinations result in a unique resistance to remove ambiguity. Also, the resistor tolerances have to get stacked up if you have a large set of resistors for the same reason.

Comment: @WerBn Not entirely sure what you are after. Your comment above adds to what you wrote and I suspect there's still more to add. But if you are looking for a mathy approach, then you may consider setting up a directed graph, \$A\$, and a conductance matrix, \$C\$. Then \$W=A^T C A\$ and \$W V = I\$ results. If you arrange the rows so as to divide up the resistors and switches into separate halves, then the Schur complement can be applied to reduce the necessary matrix work. But with your comment I'm not sure you even have switches. Maybe not. Maybe just pullable resistors? I don't know.

Comment: @WerBn Can you add a specific question to your post?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no easy mathematical formula in general, this can indeed be solved without building the full look-up table via an [ILP solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) like [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3). The key is to use conductivity, rather than resistance.

Given a known voltage drop across the unknown parallel combination of resistors, as well as a known lower resistor of the resistive divider (1k Ohms in the picture you showed), you can compute the total resistance of the unknown parallel combination.

Given this total resistance in Ohms, you can easily compute its conductance in Siemens as it's just the reciprocal:

```
Gtotal = 1 / Rtotal
```

You can do the same with all of the individual resistors that may or may not be present in the parallel combination, giving you a set of conductances `G1 ... Gn`. As parallel conductances add, we can easily create an equation for the problem:

```
Gtotal = p1 * G1 + p2 * G2 + ... + pn * Gn
```

Where `p1 ... pn` indicate whether the respective resistor is present (1) or absent (0). Now all you have to do is to find values for all the `p1 ...  pn` that satisfy this equation. To do this, you can enter the problem directly into Z3.

Note though that if your measurement is imprecise, a solution may not exist. In that case, you'll instead have to determine `p1 ... pn` so that the error in the total conductance value becomes minimal. It should still be possible to do this with Z3, but it might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: Ok. Cool.
So, the condunctance Gtotal of the above parallel resistors would be 1/78, aproximately, if all of the switches would be conducting, right?
Then, looking at the following equantion, Gtotal would be p1*100 + p2*120 + p3*140, right?
Ok, I know absolutely nothing about Z3. Where should I start to obtain my results?

Comment: @WerBn Not quite. Conductance is the reciprocal of resistance, so it's `Gtotal = p1 * (1/100) + p2 * (1/120) + p3 * (1/140)`, in Siemens.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Makes sense.
What about Z3? How do I start, considering this issue? Thanks